# Dynamically updating graphs on a Java based website

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, html

I'm currently in the progress of setting up a localhost based web application on port 8080. This application comes with my Java server application, and is used to show statistics related to the server. I currently am using a basic Java GUI to show the statistics of the server, however I wanted to make it accessible from over the web with visual representations of data.

The graphs that I will be using are as follows:

- Doughnut charts
- Filled Line Charts

The information displayed by the graph would need to be updated every second. The information that these graphs will display are things such as the servers **current** network I/O, current RAM usage, current CPU usage, the amount of threads that the server is running on, processing times for threads, etc.

As stated before, I already have all of this information being sent to a GUI in a text-based format.

The problem that I'm running into the most while looking through APIs for charts is that they all call out to another website(Such as google chart API) and then it generates an image, this image is then displayed. Doing this once per second would destroy your bandwidth, if your internet connection could even remotely keep up.

The only solution that I have personally thought of is to create a system in which a layout for a graph is drawn, then have it so the website would ''Connect the dots'' of the points on the graph. Then I would only have to update the points on the graph, then call the draw function again, but there's two problems.

1. I don't have a clue how to about doing this.
2. I'm not sure if this method would process any better than the google chart API method.

I know for a fact that this has to be possible, because applications such as (Competition)SmartFoxServer use it. Example image: [image: SmartFoxServer Remote Administration]

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use some opensource JS chart library for this. Good options: http://www.chartjs.org/ or http://www.flotcharts.org/ or http://dygraphs.com/

You get the data from your server in i.e. JSON format with AJAX request (5 s period?) and feed it to the chart library. You could use websockets to have updates triggered from server but that is slightly more difficult.

Comment: The graphs would be required to update once per second, wouldn't this be fairly taxing on the IO generating a JSON file once per second? Also, while this would take care of supplying new information to the graph when it's rendered, what about while the user is still on the page? The graphs would need to update right infront of them in real time.

Comment: Well, you have to aggregate/filter your data reasonably on the server. Obviously, you don't want to send 1 GB to your browser every 5s but 1kB of data is absolutely fine and it should be more then enough for your charts. Generating JSON on the server is very fast you don't really have to worry about that.

Comment: "generating a JSON file" why would you generate it to a file? Just send it in response when you get AJAX request.

Comment: I'll look into sending JSON based AJAX(Respectively AJAJ in this sitation, right?) responses over a Java servlet when I get back from work. I'll look into the libraries and see what I can acomplish, thanks for your response.